# live_redirect doesn't grab session correctly

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm using Phoenix liveview and am trying to add a field to the session which holds a timezone. But I have ran into some problems.

I have managed to update the session by pushing an event to the client which then updates the session with help of some javascript by making a post request to the server which updates the session.

**Pusing event to the client**

```
@impl true
def handle_event("changed_timezone", %{"timezone_selected" => timezone_selected}, socket) do
    {:noreply, push_event(socket, "store", %{key: "timezone", value: timezone_selected})}
end
```

**Module responsible for updating the session**

```
defmodule WebApp.Controllers.Session do
  @moduledoc false
  use WebApp, :controller

  def set(conn, %{"timezone" => timezone}) do
    conn
    |> fetch_session()
    |> put_session("timezone", timezone)
    |> json("ok")
  end
end
```

If I update the session with a new timezone and manually go to another page the updated session is recived correctly in the liveview's mount-function. However if i go to the same page with help of the `live_redirect` I get the old session in the mount-function. The `live_redirect` only works if I refresh the page after I have updated the session and then click on the link which redirects me to the new page using `live_redirect`

Have anyone experienced this, or have some idea what the problem might be?

Thanks